# execute code in viewwillappear once

Tags: layer, viewwillappear

I have  a few line of code in viewwillappear method. I want to execute this code only once. How can i do this. However this code is inside a loop.

`CALayer *myLayer = btn.layer;
            myLayer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
            myLayer.masksToBounds=NO;
            myLayer.borderWidth = 2.0;
            myLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
            myLayer.shadowRadius = 10.0;
            myLayer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
            myLayer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;`

Comment: What do you mean? Is this a part of the loop, and you want to execute **this** part of the code only once, or do you want to make the loop run only once? Anyway, it would be helpful if you'd post the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a `BOOL` variable `flag` (or any name you like) in .h file. set it to `NO` in viewDidLoad method. In viewWillAppear method, have a check if this code is executed before:

```
for(---)
{
if(!flag)
 {
      //execute above lines of code
   flag = YES;
 }
}
```

just in last line, make its value `YES`.

Comment: @Lotus. Please mark this answer as solution by clicking on check you are seeing here on left hand side. Thanks :)